# Does JDK11 HttpClient support trailer header?

Tags: java, java-11, java-http-client

I saw that in JDK9 [there was a support for trailers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpResponse.html#trailers--) (the `HttpResponse.trailers​()` method), but [no longer on JDK 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/jdk/incubator/http/HttpResponse.html) (the `HttpResponse.trailers​()` method is absent).

I am currently using JDK11 and when I try my request:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                                 .uri(uri)
                                 .GET()
                                 .build();


HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(request, BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

I face a `java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.io.IOException: no statuscode in response`. It only fails when I am requesting a page with trailer headers.
Any help welcome. Thanks

Comment: HI, AFAIK they are not supported.

Comment: Similar Question: [*Is there a way to read HTTP trailers with the Java 11 HttpClient?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78029369/642706)