# Is there a way to read HTTP trailers with the Java 11 HttpClient?

Tags: java, httpclient, java-http-client

Currently using the Java 11 HttpClient to make http requests and it appears there isn't an obvious way to read response trailers. These responses are streamed back to the client - the Java 11 HttpClient is being used because it has better streaming support.

Any suggestions? Hacky answers accepted

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything at all. I found some mentions of an "incubating feature" to support trailers, but apparently it never got added. My feeling would be to start looking at other libraries.

Comment: Did you try to read a trailer response with HttpClient?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The question looks like an exact duplicate of the following question: [java - Does JDK11 HttpClient support trailer header? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63905818/does-jdk11-httpclient-support-trailer-header).

Comment: @SergeyVyacheslavovichBrunov But the other Question has *no* Answers posted.

Comment: The java.net.httpclient doesn't currently support trailers, in any version of the protocol. Is there a specific use case for that?